# Bulk insert error, when loading date format

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

I'm receiving a lot of .csv files that I need to bulk insert into a SQL table.

In the csv file the date format is in YYYY-MM-DD and a seperate column for time which is in format HH:MM:SS.

```
"2016-11-24";"01:00:16"
```

In my table I created the two columns as a date datatype and a time datatype and using this piece of code to insert:

```
BULK
INSERT [dbo].[table_name]
FROM 'filepath'
WITH
(
FIRSTROW = 2,
FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

But I get this error:

```
Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 37
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the     specified codepage) for row 2, column 1 (date).
```

If I use a normal insert into statement it works...

Comment: are you positive the date arrives as yyyy-mm-dd and not as yyyy/mm/dd

Comment: Yes, it arrives that way. 2016-12-19

Comment: and codepage is OK, too? It would seem you have a character mapping mismatch, which doesn't fit the selected CP. Are your csv using different encoding perhaps?

Comment: Hi.  Are the values `"2016-11-24";"01:00:16"` an example?  Or are these taken from a row that failed to import?

Comment: It is taken from at row that fails to import.

Comment: Notepad++ says its ANSI format

Answer (score 0):

First check your physical table date and time columns data type. It has datetime format, which means first you move all .csv file data to a temporary table with `varchar` datatype. After inserted in temporary table then move to physical table with use of datetime conversion.

Comment: Can I do that in one step, because I'm getting new data every 10 mins that I need to insert.

Comment: Yes possible,write store procedure.First insert into temp table in next line move to physical table